idm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupted; while booting through usb to install ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo x220 tablet laptop. I have read all the requirements to install this version on my laptop, and my system contains all of those reqs.
While booting through a USB, first I get the error of :
error: /boot/ not found
After a few seconds, i can see the window of try or install Ubuntu, I click on install Ubuntu and then I get the following error for a few seconds:
idm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupted
After that, ubuntu gets started, and then on the screen of how you want to install Ubuntu, I don't get any option and get stuck on that
enter image description here
I have tried using multiple USBs, I want to use dual boot: ubuntu and Windows 10 as well. I have a 1Tb SSD drive, have made four partitions on that, will install Ubuntu  on the last partition.
I will be grateful for a brief descriptive answer.
Thanks!

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
